# I moved my JVM to a RAM disk using imdisk, but cannot run java from that location?

Tags: eclipse, jvm, java

So I am trying to improve Eclipse performance, someone suggested a while ago to move the JVM to a RAM disk, I did that with imdisk, I basically copied the jdk folder to that disk and pointed there from eclipse.ini - eclipse does not load!

Comment: Does it give you an error message or produce a crash log?  What's it telling you?

Comment: Says that windows cannot find that file...even though the files are all there and I can click on them. I can open text files just fine. But when I try any executable, it fails.

Comment: Idk if it's an indexing issue?

Comment: Does the path contain spaces?  I've seen that cause problems before.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Basically I just tried putting putty on the RAM disk and running it...no avail. Same error, says that windows cannot find the file or the path is incorrect. But I can open text files. It's kind of a mystery..

Comment: If you were on Linux, I'd say that the disk was mounted with `noexec` turned on.  Is it possible that when you mounted your RAM disk, it used such an option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JVM loads almost completely during the startup of Eclipse.

The major speed issue is the filesystem underlying the workspace and Eclipse itself.  Especially for Windows with Anti-Virus this can be very slow.

I suggest that instead of working with moving the JDK you should analyze your system to find out what makes it slow and go from there.  If it starts swapping nothing else but fixing that will work.